# How do I configure environment variables in cmder?

Tags: cmder

I'm using cmder (https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder), and would like to be able to:

- Configure entries to be automatically added the PATH when I start cmder
- Configure environment variables that will be automatically set when I start cmder

How do I do this?

Comment: Is there a tabbed console app? Preferably with ctrl-tab or some other shortcut for switching between them? Windows really needs something like virtual tty's. I've seen some that have transparent windows and stuff, but that's a fluff feature that doesn't help. Edit: ok, I was thinking of conemu, which cmder appears to use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a user startup script in `cmder\config\user-profile.cmd`. To add items to your PATH, you can do the following;

```
@set PATH=<path_of_your_item>;%PATH%
```

Comment: Not sure what version it changed, but now it seems to be `cmder\vendor\init.bat`.

Comment: No, init.bat gets overwritten. Thats why its placed in the vendor folder.

Comment: Seems like you're right.

Comment: Do you know why this is happening to me? `call` does not source a .cmd file correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523506/sourcing-a-cmd-file-with-call-from-windows-cmder

Comment: Doesn't work when you rerun the terminal after close it

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can set them on startup under Settings -> Startup -> Environment and add

```
set PATH=<path_of_your_item>;%PATH%`.
```

[image: Screenshot Example]